# Cannot debug project created with NB6.9.1 within NB7+ (has JAR dependency which uses JNI)

Tags: java, netbeans, java-native-interface, migration, netbeans-7

I just tried to migrate our working Java projects from **Netbeans 6.9.1** to **Netbeans 7.2** and I'm experiencing a problem due to one of our project dependencies being an *external JAR which uses JNI*.

I created a copy of our project directory and simply opened the copies of NB projects originally created with the older version of the IDE. Everything went smooth. I can build the projects and run compiled executable JAR-s outside of Netbeans without any problems.

However when I try to debug the project, the application fails to init properly due to said dependency JAR with JNI. It's like the JAR is failing to find a DLL associated with it (giving me `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` as a result). This does not happen with 6.9.1!

Why would this be happening? Do I need to explicitly set `java.library.path` in NB7+?

There were no changes made to the projects (not by us) and the same JDK is being used in both versions of the IDE. I suspect the newer version applies changes to the project setup silently and breaks something in the process. Anyone experienced something similar?

***Edit 1:***

Tried fiddling with `project.properties`, setting `-Djava.library.path` VM arg, different JDKs/JREs, ... all to no avail. This is driving me nuts. Obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Try disabling Compile on save, might be enabled by default when you upgraded. Just a thought.

Comment: @javydreamercsw thanks, but Compile on save is disabled. I also know compiler options took effect since I double checked `java.library.path` property in code and it had the expected value.

Comment: *VM options, not compiler options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what went wrong. This only became apparent after I got source of the external JAR (`ext.jar` from now on) in form of a Netbeans project so I could debug it.

`ext.jar` may load one of several DLLs depending on certain conditions. It constructs a file path to the appropriate DLL by using `SomeClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile()` and then calls `System.load(path)` with it's value. This path is different between the two versions of Netbeans. `ext.jar` is actually being used by another JAR (which is also a Netbeans project), which in turn is used by the main executable JAR of the application (also a project).

```
Main JAR (Netbeans project)
 ˪ Common JAR (Netbeans project)
     ˪ External JAR with JNI (ext.jar)
```

All external libraries in our project setup are placed within a directory at the same level where all the projects reside. This enables multiple projects to use a common set of libraries. Projects use relative paths to reference the libs.

```
CommonLibraries
MainJARProjdir
CommonJARProjdir
RandomProjdir1
…
RandomProjdirN
```

When `Main` is built, `Common` must be built before it (`Common` is a project dependecy of `Main`). In the process of building `Common` (by default) all dependency JARs get copied to `${common.proj.dir}/dist/lib`. The copy process is of course unaware of the fact that it should copy DLLs along with `ext.jar`.

The root of the problem is however **different handling** of dependencies in **6.9.1** and **7+**. If I specify `ext.jar` to be a dependency to both `Main` and `Common` (which is what was done, even though `Main` doesn't directly use any code from it) 6.9.1 will use the `../CommonLibraries/ext.jar` when debugging, which always has all the required DLLs beside it, while 7+ will always use `${common.proj.dir}/dist/lib/ext.jar`, which is missing the DLLs.

After recognizing what the problem is, the solution becomes trivial. I added a `-post-clean` target to `build.xml` of `Common`, which simply copies required DLLs from `../CommonLibraries/` to `${common.proj.dir}/dist/lib/` after each clean. It worked. This should be done either way – for completeness sake.

The reason for different handling of dependencies in the two versions of the IDE appears to be a new checkbox which is present in `Project Properties/Build/Packaging` called ***Copy Dependent Libraries***. Ticking that off for `Common` also works. Note that this checkbox is enabled by default (even for library projects).